# Backbone template render html content

Tags: html, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

i have a code something like below which from the server side returns something like this 
e.g `sometext1 <span class='boldclass'> somespantext </span> sometext2`

so can any one tell me the best way to display this text as 'sometext1 **somespantext** sometext2' and not something like `sometext1 <span class='boldclass'> somespantext </span> sometext2` ??

**Backbone underscore template**

```
<%- item.value %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> **template** `_.template(templateString, [settings])`
>
> [...] If you wish to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use `<%- … %>`

You're using `<%- ... %>` for `item.value` and `<%-` HTML encodes. If `item.value` contains HTML that you want on the page then just use `<%= ... %>`:

```
<%= item.value %>
```